# Visualizing the embedded space in Probabilistic Matrix factorization for recommendation

Tags: pca, data-visualization, recommender-system

Is there a preferable way to visualize the embedded space in Probabilistic Matrix factorization for recommendation? Should I run PCA after getting the User and Item matrix? If so, I should then merge the two matrix before applying PCA, right? [Here](https://sandipanweb.wordpress.com/2017/04/04/probabilistic-matrix-factorization-with-a-generative-model-in-python/) you can find an example of visualization. Unfortunately there is not much information on how to replicate the graph. I also noticed that some people just plot the first two or three elements of the latent vectors.. While being certainly a possibility, I am not sure whether that is the standard approach.

Comment: Look at plot subtitles. These are factors/principal components like in PCA

Comment: This seems to be the case there! However, the name "factor vector" is also used to name the latent variables in the PMF. Hence, the confusion. The only clue of PCA is when he says "projection onto the first 2 vectors of the latent space". The Thus, Should I then run PCA with the U and V matrix merged?